# Type of information about nodes on Alfresco server possible to obtain?

Tags: android, alfresco, getter

I am using the **Alfresco Mobile SDK for Android**, available on the Alfresco website.

I am trying to obtain the following information from the Alfresco server, if possible with an existing easymethod (maybe not documented inside the doumentation provided):

- the ***number of characters inside a `Document`*** (I tried the method `getContentStreamLength()` that you can apply on an Object of type Document)
- the ***size of a `Document`***, and then the size of a `Folder`, or if there is directly a method to obtain the size of a Folder. Which will be the unity of this size (Go, ...) retrieved?
- the ***list of person a `Node` is shared with***
- the ***number of Folder children, and File children of a `Folder`***

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***the number of characters inside a Document***

It's not possible. Indeed depending on what type of document (text, office document, images, movies, etc...) one character is relevant or not. So no it's not possible.

***the size of a Document***

Yes. It's possible simply use `Document.getContentStreamLength()` . It returns the size of document in bytes. -1 if there's no content.

***the size of a Folder***

No. It's not possible.

***the number of Folder children, and File children of a Folder***

It's possible to know the number of sub-Folder or Documents inside the folder limited to level -1. In others terms if the folder has a depth more than 1 it's not possible to list everything. We are limited to the level -1

You can use those methods `DocumentFolderService.getDocuments()` or `DocumentFolderService.getFolders()` to list folders or documents.

***the list of person a Node is shared with***

There's no support for the moment around permission management.

Hope it helps.

NB : If you want new features available inside the SDK, Feel free to post any requirements to https://issues.alfresco.com/jira

Comment: As Jean-Marie wrote most of the SDK, you can consider this answer as authoritative as they come!

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! 
It really helps me to know what is possible and what is not yet.
Even if not everything is possible with the Alfresco Mobile SDK, it is really a great tool to program easily a lot of useful functions of the Alfresco platform.